# How can I properly link the library in such a way that the compiler gets the function declaration from the library?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I know this may be a very basic question as I am a beginner to C. I have a shared library that contains a function. I am using that same function in my own c file. Whenever I compile and link the shared library, it throws and error: implicit declaration of function. How can I properly link the library in such a way that the compiler gets the function declaration from the library? The shared library I am using is mach-o.

Comment: This is _compile_ error and _not_ a _link_ error. There is _no_ declaration for the given function. (e.g.) There is _no_ `void external_function(int abc,int def);`. That's [probably] because your `.c` file is _not_ doing (e.g.) `#include <external_lib.h>` at the top. So, you have to figure out what the true `.h` file name is and add the `#include`

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a `.h` file which describes the parameter-lists and return-values of every function that exists in that binary library.  The library itself consists only of binary executable code and does not provide that information.

Comment: I was doing something similar to this tutorial:
https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html

In the code for my shared library, it contained my function. Then, in my main function, I called that same function. What is the difference between that tutorial and my case?

Comment: Oh I understand. The tutorial has a header file too and this describes the function. Thank you

Comment: I have one question though. What happens when I do not have header files. For example, if I just have a shared library and want to implement some function from the shared library into my code. How would I do that?

Comment: @waslemon12 — if you don't have the header, you can't use the functions from the library directly.  Headers provide the glue that holds systems together; they are crucial to (modern) C.  In this context, 'modern' means 'anything written in the 21st century'.

Comment: @waslemon12: “Implementing” a function means writing code that does the function. If you just want to call a function and do not have a header for it, you can write your own declaration of the function if you know the types of parameters it takes and the type of value it returns. But it is unusual to have the object/archive/library files that provide function implementations without having the header files that declare the functions, unless maybe the publisher provided headers for one language and you want to use the library in another language.

Comment: Re “The library itself consists only of binary executable code”: “Library” is a general term that may encompass everything needed to provide the implementations of behavior, including object modules, headers and/or other interface descriptions, and documentation.

Comment: Okay I understand.